# Wordpress sidebar widget not being rendered by wordpress properly

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I have used the following PHP code to register a sidebar:

```
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' =>   'Owner\'s main page intro left sidebar.',
    'id' =>     'main-left-sidebar',
    'description' => 'This is the main side bar of the theme i.e. the information of the author on the index page will be displayed using it. Note: It MUST have a single text widget or otherwise it may distort the theme',
    'before_widget' =>  '',
    'after_widget' =>   '</p>',
    'before_title' =>   '<div class="porse"><h3 id="titlehead">',
    'after_title' =>    '</h3></div><p class="porse-lead">'
));
```

So that when I add a widget (I'm working with a text widget), it generates something like the following:

```
<div class="porse">
    <h3 id="titlehead">I'm Kamran Ahmed</h3>
</div>
<p class="porse-lead">I make websites. I help small businesses, start-ups, individuals, and fellow web agencies make the most of their web presence.</p>
```

But whenever I add a widget to the sidebar, it keeps producing the following markup:

```
<div class="porse">
    <h3 id="titlehead">I am Kamran Ahmed</h3>
</div>
<p class="porse-lead">          </p>
<div class="textwidget">I make websites. I help small businesses, start-ups, individuals, and fellow web agencies make the most of their web presence.</div>
<p></p>
```

Can anyone please tell me, what I'm doing wrong here. Why isn't it producing the markup that I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `<div>` tags inside `<p>` tags.

Try this instead:

```
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' =>   'Owner\'s main page intro left sidebar.',
    'id' =>     'main-left-sidebar',
    'description' => 'This is the main side bar of the theme i.e. the information of the author on the index page will be displayed using it. Note: It MUST have a single text widget or otherwise it may distort the theme',
    'before_widget' =>  '',
    'after_widget' =>   '</div>',
    'before_title' =>   '<div class="porse"><h3 id="titlehead">',
    'after_title' =>    '</h3></div><div class="porse-lead">'
));
```

Comment: Because, if I place it in `before_widget`, it would enclose the whole widget (including the title) which I don't want.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please try this and report back the result please. The `<div class="textwidget"></div>` is being generated because you are using a text widget in WordPress.